# I need to use scrollview correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, xml-layout

I have 3 buttons and scroll view contains text and images.
I want the scrollview effect only for the images and texts and my 3 buttons fixed over the scrollview how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FrameLayout`.

An example of a top bar with three buttons over a `ScrollView` with images is demonstrated below.

`FrameLayout`'s render their children in the order they are declared. For the example below, the `ScrollView` is rendered first, and the LinearLayout button bar is rendered last. This places the bar above the scrollview and gives the desired effect.

The reason the `ScrollView` has a `LinearLayout` as a child, is because they can only have one child.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thank you so much, another Question :) How can i set the buttons to the bottom of the screen ?

Comment: Use android:`layout_gravity="bottom"` on the button bar layout.